# Count the number of instances of values using groupby pandas

Tags: pandas, lambda, group-by, apply

I have the following timeseries data frame with `id` and `pid's`. I am interested to find out the no of pauses (`id 0`) and no of movements (`id not 0`) for each `pid`.

Here I consider the minimum id's to be at least 3 (`id==0 >=3`)

```
dateTime                          id            pid
5/21/2016 15:23 3:23:25            0             a
5/21/2016 15:23 3:23:26            0             a
5/21/2016 15:23 3:23:27            0             a
5/21/2016 15:23 3:23:28            0             a
5/21/2016 15:23 3:23:29            0             a
5/21/2016 15:23 3:23:30            1             a
5/21/2016 15:23 3:23:31            2             a
5/21/2016 15:23 3:23:32            3             a
5/21/2016 15:23 3:23:33            0             a
5/21/2016 15:23 3:23:34            1             a
5/21/2016 15:23 3:40:25            0             a
5/21/2016 15:23 3:40:26            0             a
5/21/2016 15:23 3:40:27            0             a
5/21/2016 15:23 3:40:28            1             a
5/21/2016 15:23 3:40:29            1             a
5/21/2016 15:23 3:23:35            0             b
5/21/2016 15:23 3:23:36            0             b
5/21/2016 15:30 3:30:02            0             b
5/21/2016 15:30 3:30:03            2             b
5/21/2016 15:30 3:30:04            3             b
5/21/2016 15:30 3:30:05            1             b
5/21/2016 15:30 3:30:06            2             b
5/21/2016 15:30 3:30:07            0             b
```

I am expecting the following output for the above data

```
nr_paused   nr_move     pid
 2          2       a
 1          1       b

nr_paused = Occurrences of id '0'  for more than 3 times then each packet should be counted as 1. 
In the above example, there are two such instances (rows 1-5 and 11-13) hence nr_paused for id 'a' is 2
Similarly, for b nr_paused=1 (rows 16-18)
The count nr_move should be id > 0 rows
```

Comment: What you want is not clear.  You're getting `True` and `False` because your lambda evaluates a logical operator (`>=`) and logical operators exists to return `True` or `False`.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `df.groupby(['pid', 'id']).size()`

Comment: @sshr it's unclear how you do the counting. Do you count packets of 3 consecutives as +1? be specific

Comment: Hi Boud.. Count 0 packets only if there are more than 3 rows. In the above example, we can ignore last row.